# What is the proper way to traverse an "ADT" in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to implement a very basic lambda reducer. The first question that comes up is what sort of datatype does one use to implement the AST? [In Haskell this would be an ADT](http://lpaste.net/148755). In Rust, it seems right is to use an enum and `Box`es:

```
enum Term{
    Num(i64),
    Plus(Box<Term>, Box<Term>),
    Var(i64),
    Lam(i64, Box<Term>),
    App(Box<Term>, Box<Term>)
}
```

This seems to be a good choice, but since I am a newb at Rust, it could very well be that the question I have -- that follows -- is simply that I have chosen the wrong datatype, and that, if I had chosen the right datatype representation, my problem would be gone.  If this happens to be the case, please do let me know!

Now on to one step reduction.  Following the Haskell code reference, we end up with something like:

```
fn reduceOneStep(t: Term) -> (Term, bool) {
    match t {
        Term::Num(a) => (t, false),
        Term::Plus(t1, t2) =>
        match (*t1, *t2) {
            (Term::Num(a), Term::Num(b)) => (Term::Num(a + b), true),
            (Term::Num(a), w) =>
            match reduceOneStep(w) {
              (t, b) => if b { (Term::Plus(t1, Box::new(t)), true) } else { (Term::Plus(t1, t2), false) }
            },
            _ => (Term::Num(1), false) //ignore .. this is just to satisfy typing and totality
        },
        x => (Term::Num(1), false) //ignore .. this is just to satisfy typing and totality
    }
}
```

However, the line

```
(t, b) => if b { (Term::Plus(t1, Box::new(t)), true) } else { (Term::Plus(t1, t2), false) }
```

fails compilation.  The reason is that I "used a moved value t1"
I don't really understand this error, nor how to get around it.  I've tried some other variants, but they don't get around the problem.  My question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, enums are the Rust way to implement ADTs.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Sorry for the confusion.  My first "question" wasn't really a question.  It was rhetorical, and my way of explaining that I am trying to mirror a piece of Haskell code.  However, I am a newb at this language, so it seems reasonable that if anyone has a suggestion about my datatype that I would love to hear about that.  I have changed the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

(Side note: this would probably better if you used the [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/index.html) type instead of a tuple with a boolean inside it. I'll stick with the way you wrote it for this answer though.)

The error message says that you can't use the moved values `t1` and `t2`, because those values were moved when you dereferenced them and did matching on them.

The information that was stored in `t1` and `t2` is now owned by the variables `a`, `w`, and `t` in that branch of the match expression, so you have to use those. If I'm wrong please correct me.

So you can go towards getting your example to work if, within the line:

```
(t, b) => if b { (Term::Plus(t1, Box::new(t)), true) } else { (Term::Plus(t1, t2), false) }
```

You replace `t1` with `Box::new(Term::Num(a))`, and `t2` with `Box::new(w)`. That, with some indentation added, is:

```
(t, b) => if b {
  (Term::Plus(Box::new(Term::Num(a)), Box::new(t)), true)
} else {
  (Term::Plus(Box::new(Term::Num(a)), Box::new(w)), false)
}
```

This fails too though, because the call `reduceOneStep(w)` took ownership of `w`. That can be fixed by making `reduceOneStep` borrow its argument instead:

```
fn reduceOneStep(t: &Term) -> (Term, bool) {
  match t {
    &Term::Num(a) => (*t, false),
    &Term::Plus(t1, t2) =>
    match (*t1, *t2) {
      (Term::Num(a), Term::Num(b)) => (Term::Num(a + b), true),
      (Term::Num(a), w) =>
      match reduceOneStep(&w) {
        (t, b) => if b {
          (Term::Plus(Box::new(Term::Num(a)), Box::new(t)), true)
        } else {
          (Term::Plus(Box::new(Term::Num(a)), Box::new(w)), false)
        }
      },
      _ => (Term::Num(1), false) //ignore .. this is just to satisfy typing and totality
    },
    x => (Term::Num(1), false) //ignore .. this is just to satisfy typing and totality
  }
}
```

But this has more errors, saying `cannot move out of borrowed content`, pointing to where it returns `*t`. This is because it can't both give the borrow back to the owner, and return a part of it as a result, because one could be freed and the other would be left hanging. One way to fix this is to `#[derive(Clone)]` for the `Term` enum, and use that:

```
fn reduceOneStep(t: &Term) -> (Term, bool) {
  match t {
    &Term::Num(a) => (t.clone(), false),
    &Term::Plus(t1, t2) =>
    match (*t1, *t2) {
      (Term::Num(a), Term::Num(b)) => (Term::Num(a + b), true),
      (Term::Num(a), w) =>
      match reduceOneStep(&w) {
        (t, b) => if b {
          (Term::Plus(Box::new(Term::Num(a)), Box::new(t)), true)
        } else {
          (Term::Plus(Box::new(Term::Num(a)), Box::new(w.clone())), false)
        }
      },
      _ => (Term::Num(1), false) //ignore .. this is just to satisfy typing and totality
    },
    x => (Term::Num(1), false) //ignore .. this is just to satisfy typing and totality
  }
}
```

But this still has the same error. Huh. The error message has this hint below it: `` help: to prevent the move, use `ref t1` or `ref mut t1` to capture value by reference ``. Then after fixing some mismatched types and fiddling with box derefs and borrows, I finally got this to work:

```
fn reduceOneStep(t: &Term) -> (Term, bool) {
  match t {
    &Term::Num(a) => (t.clone(), false),
    &Term::Plus(ref t1, ref t2) =>
    match (&**t1, &**t2) {
      (&Term::Num(a), &Term::Num(b)) => (Term::Num(a + b), true),
      (&Term::Num(a), w) =>
      match reduceOneStep(&w) {
        (t, b) => if b {
          (Term::Plus(Box::new(Term::Num(a)), Box::new(t)), true)
        } else {
          (Term::Plus(Box::new(Term::Num(a)), Box::new(w.clone())), false)
        }
      },
      _ => (Term::Num(1), false) //ignore .. this is just to satisfy typing and totality
    },
    x => (Term::Num(1), false) //ignore .. this is just to satisfy typing and totality
  }
}
```

I'm a beginner with rust right now, so if someone can help me understand why this works, I'll be very grateful.